# Дублирование символов при вводе/выводе

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int c;

    while(c = getchar() != EOF){
       putchar(c);
    }
}
```

В консоли ввожу символы, они выводятся нормально. Но как только нажимаю <kbd>Enter</kbd> т.е. ввожу `'\n'`, помимо перехода на новую строку в консоли дублируется и предыдущая строка.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Так и должно быть. Что дальше?

Comment: Добавьте скобки вокруг `c = getchar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В консоли ввожу символы

OK, вы наполняете стандартный вход символами. Но они при этом никуда не попадают. А как только нажимается <kbd>Enter</kbd> - они становятся доступными для чтения, и ваш цикл (с поправкой) вычитывает их из стандартного потока и выводит. Всё работает так, как и должно работать.

```
/*
 * Тут мы ввели строку "qwerty" и нажали Enter
 */
while( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
   /* 
    * А тут мы эту строку читаем по 
    * одному символу и выводим:
    */
   putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввод и вывод *буферизован*. Поэтому...

Одна строка - когда вы ВВОДИТЕ символы. Они не считываются, пока не нажата клавиша `Enter`. Нажали - курсор переместился на новую строку, пошло считывание из буфера, и вывод всех символов с помощью `putchar`. Так образуется вторая строка.